# Is it possible to compile a single javascript library with webpack?

Tags: npm, webpack

I have a project where I use [deck.gl](https://deck.gl/) to create web maps. It works fine, however, I need the functionality of drawing polygons and, for that, the deck.gl documentation tells me to use [nebula.gl](https://nebula.gl/). The sample of the functionality that I need can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/deckgl-and-nebulagl-editablegeojsonlayer-no-react-p9yrs?file=/app.js

The problem that I have is that on the nebula.gl documentation there's no library compiled to be used on a `<script>` tag. They only work with the library installed through npm or yarn, then the only way I managed to make it work so far was by compiling the entire project with webpack... In my specific case, I'd like to avoid compiling the entire project and I'd prefer using a compiled js file with the `<script>` tag.

Is it possible to compile npm libraries with webpack into a single js file? Just so I can use this nebula.gl library with a `<script>` tag on my webpage? Or am I misinterpreting the way I should be using webpack?

Comment: Can you not use ES modules?

Comment: @connexo When you say ES modules you mean importing new libraries with `import`? That's exactly what I want to avoid using in my case :/... I'd like to find a way of using the library without having to compile it with webpack. The ideal scenario would be loading this library on my page and then using its functionalities with pure javascript...

Comment: I'm talking real ES modules *in the browser*, no webpack or bundling involved. Let the browser do the lifting.

Comment: @connexo I'm not sure if I understood how I'd implement it. Could you elaborate a little more or send me some references of what you mean?

Comment: Just read about ES Modules resp. import and export on MDN. It's just basic usage of import and export.